# download youtube video in C++

Tags: video, download, youtube

I am writing a method that should download the .flv video from youtube and save it to hard drive. I've read all around everything, source code available, forums, but I cannot get my code to work. I think youtube has removed this feature and it is no longer possible to download videos. But then comes the question: how do some programs free and commercial do it?

Here is my code:

```
    WebClient^ client = gcnew WebClient();

 String^ page = client->DownloadString(URL);

  String^ videoId = innerValue(URL, "v=", "&");

  String^ details = client->DownloadString("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=" + videoId);

  String^ t1 = innerValue(page, "&t=", "&");

  String^ t2 = HttpUtility::UrlDecode(innerValue(details, "&token=", "&"));

  String^ videoUrl = String::Format("http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id={0}&t={1}&fmt={2}", videoId, t2, fmt);

  client->DownloadFile(videoUrl, gcnew String(file));
```

InnerValue method just gets the text between the two params. No matter if I use "t1" or "t2", it still does not work!

Let me know what I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for this, this might be helpful to you.
So suppose you want to download some youtube video what you must do is add ss too it. Let me explain with example. Suppose your video is :

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz

change it to

> https://ssyoutube.com/watch?v=xyz

by using simple string manipulation in c++.

Then after this use something mentioned in this answer to question "[how-to-click-a-button-on-website-with-c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813120/11526227)"

I prefer using Selenium. As it is good for automation purposes.

Using this you can try

1. clicking on the More button
2. select desired type of video
3. then download button to start

I think this will download the video. I know this kind of a hack and not what you are looking for but for fulfilling the usecase this could be used

Let me know if this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

*Attempt to download the url you are forming using your browser.* If it works, you may have to spoof the user-agent settings when sending your request.

Comment: Then obviously it won't work in your application. Try to find the way flv urls are being generated.