# How to click a button on website with C++

Tags: c++, web-crawler

I'm designing a web crawler with C++,but there is a web page asking me "Do you at least 18 years of age?" when I first fetch the web page by using `URLDownloadToFileW`,and of course I must click YES.

In javascript,I can use `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();` to simulate a button click,so is there any other way to solve such problem with C++?

Comment: Mostly likely this is not going to work, at least not easily. If the desired content is not already loaded, then you are supposed to send another request to website. It's impossible to guess what that is.

Answer (score 0):

That is not really easy to do, but if you want to do it, you need several requests.

What the click (i.e. `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();` in JavaScript) does is to trigger an associated click event. Your first step should be to find the event handler code and take a look into it. The event may for example send another (AJAX) request to the website. If that is the case, you have to perform the request in C++ in your crawler, too. Many sites also use cookies to store the user's answer to such questions (or at least the fact that the user selected "I'm at least 18 years of age"). So your crawler has to accept such cookies, too, and store them between requests.

I am aware of the fact that this answer is rather general, but it is difficult to give a more specific answer without knowing the exact website you are crawling.

**Alternative approach:** Instead of writing a crawler that downloads the website content directly, you might utilize frameworks like **[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)**. Selenium allows to automate a browser and is intended to be used for testing, but one could also use it to crawl a website. The advantage is that you can also perfom things like clicks easier in the browser, given you know the ID or the XPath of the element you want to click. This might be easier to do than a "classical" crawler.

However, you should be aware that many websites have some kind of protection against flooding them with requests in place. That is, if you intent to do a lot of request to the same server in a short amount of time, you might get blocked from the server. So try to limit the requests to the absolute minimum.